# Cannot invoke method leftshift() on null object in spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

Below code is the very basic example of spock testing. When I run it, it gives the following error

`Cannot invoke method leftshift() on null object`

Why is it and how can I make my code work?

Also, what exactly are the uses of `leftshift` and `rightshift` in spock.

```
import spock.lang.*;

class Publisher {
     List <Subscriber> subscribers      
     void send (String message){}   
}

interface Subscriber {
    void receive(String message)
}

public class Test1 extends Specification {

    Publisher publisher = new Publisher()
    def subscriber = Mock(Subscriber)
    def subscriber2 = Mock(Subscriber)

    def setup() {           
        (publisher.subscribers) << subscriber
        (publisher.subscribers) << subscriber2
    }

    def "should send message to subscriber"() {

        when:
        publisher.send("hello")

        then:
        1 * subscriber.receive("hello")
        1 * subscriber2.receive("hello")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's a bug in your Publisher class, which doesn’t initialize its `subscribers` field (hence the NPE). `list << elem` is a Groovy shortcut for `list.add(elem)`. To learn more about mocking with Spock, visit http://docs.spockframework.org.

PS: Please don't double-post here and on http://forum.spockframework.org (either is fine).

Comment: and how to workaround this bug? is this bug reported as an issue somewhere?